# Print record from Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I want to print the record from the database.
First, the user enters the value in an entry box
then if it matches in database values then print it (like user enter 2914 and 2914 is in the database then print it)
My database whole column values are printing (means connection ok) but, the searching operation not works

```
tf = StringVar()

def getvalue():
    n=tf.get()
    connection = sqlite3.connect("database.sqlite3")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT table.col1 FROM table ;")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    print(results)
    if n==results:
        print (results)
    else:
        print("not there")
            
#*************************************
Label(root, text="'Enter Network ASN'").grid(row = 3, column = 6, sticky = W, pady = 14) 
Entry(root, textvariable = tf).grid(row=3, column=8, sticky = E, pady = 14) #entry textbox

WSignUp = Button(root, text="Search", command=getvalue).grid(row=5, column=7, sticky=W, pady = 14) #button

root.mainloop()
```

My database values are  like [('2914',), ('13830',), ('13768',), ('33597',), ('21219',), ('21949',), ('209',), ('701',), ('1239',), ('1273',), ('1759',), ('2828',)]

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your SQL query, The correct SQL query would be something as follows

`SELECT table.col1 FROM table WHERE table.col1 = user_entered_value;`

This query will return all values in the table where the column matches value in the `WHERE` clause. If there are multiple values you are checking for then use

`SELECT table.col1 FROM table WHERE table.col1 IN list_of_values;`

These queries will not be protected against SQL injection so you will need to look into using prepared statements with the SQLite library as I am not familiar with it. You can then go through the returned results from the query and generate the GUI accordingly.

The issue with the query that you used was that it was just getting all values that were in the table with no comparisons to the data your user has entered.

Comment: SELECT table.col1 FROM table WHERE table.col1 = n; but it is considering n as a column giving error no such column

Comment: You need to add your tables schema to your question as I do not know the way your table is created.

Comment: SELECT table.col1 FROM table  WHERE  table.col1 =?", (n,) I have solved this way anyways thanks for forwarding the attention that we can pass a variable with SQLite queries.